# Use PHP To Generate Random Decimal Beteween Two Decimals

Tags: php, random

I need to generate a random number, to the 10th spot between 2 decimals in PHP.

Ex. A rand number between 1.2 and 5.7. It would return 3.4

How can I do this?

Comment: It's silly, but I needed a function. As follows:

function drand($low, $high) {
  return mt_rand($low*100, $high*100) / 100;
 }

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use:

```
rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10
```

or even better:

```
mt_rand ($min*10, $max*10) / 10
```

Comment: fwiw - as of php 7.1, rand is an alias of mt_rand

Answer (score 6):

You could do something like:

```
rand(12, 57) / 10
```

PHP's random function allows you to only use integer limits, but you can then divide the resulting random number by 10.

Answer (score 6):

A more general solution would be:

```
function count_decimals($x){
   return  strlen(substr(strrchr($x+"", "."), 1));
}

public function random($min, $max){
   $decimals = max(count_decimals($min), count_decimals($max));
   $factor = pow(10, $decimals);
   return rand($min*$factor, $max*$factor) / $factor;
}

$answer = random(1.2, 5.7);
```

Comment: for those going after this solution, nowadays a slight better approach would be to embed the `count_decimals()` function as a closure inside that `random()`, so it is hidden from the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to as function

```
/**
 * @param float $min
 * @param float $max
 * @param int $digit
 * @return float|int
 */
public function randomDecimal(float $min, float $max, int $digit = 2): float|int
{
    return mt_rand($min * 10, $max * 10) / pow(10, $digit);
}
```