# PHP rand function generates wrong values

Tags: php, random

I've got a little issue with the php function rand. Array is an array with numbers between 0.1 and 1.

```
 $min = $this->array[0]*10;
 $max = $this->array[1]*10;
 array_push($this->motor, rand($min, $max), rand($min,$max));
```

Once in a while rand generates 0 the rest of the time the rand function works fine. Does somebody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what does $this->array contains??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PHP To Generate Random Decimal Beteween Two Decimals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419501/use-php-to-generate-random-decimal-beteween-two-decimals)

Answer (score 2):

`rand` only works with integer precision. All float input is converted to integers. Floats by definition aren't exactly precise, a value just slightly under 1 will get truncated down to 0.

Comment: you would need to divide by 10 afterwords. eg `rand($min*10, $max*10) / 10`

Comment: @Bruno Again, floating point arithmetic is **not precise**. If your input is just below 0.1 then multiplying it by 10 will still result in a value < 1.

Comment: @decez assuming the min value is 0.1 and max is 1 multiplying by 10 would result in min 1 and max 10, then divide by 10 would result in the desired result.

Comment: @Bruno You'll have to provide a reproducible example here. `rand` should not return `0` if its input is >= 1. We're only going on your word here at the moment.

Comment: https://ideone.com/Fm5rxH here's 100 iterations of rand, no 0 is returned. We would need to see what `$this->array` is returning when the result from rand is 0.

Comment: array contains two random digits between 0.1 and 1 which are generated by rand(1,10)/10

Comment: @Bruno So you're already starting with floating point arithmetic. How can you be sure the value is >= 0.1?

Comment: i thought that the min val rand(1,10) is 1 so 1/10 is the smallest possible value

Comment: @Bruno Do you understand the meaning of *floating point arithmetic is __not precise__*?

Comment: @Bruno Not with the limited information given. You need to somehow use a different algorithm that avoids such floating point arithmetic, or you need to use `bc` functions and strings to do *precise* decimal arithmetic. Which solution fits your problem best I have no idea, since I know nothing about the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$randomNumber = (float)rand($min, $max) / (float)$max;
```